# How can I catch an ExtendedSocketException?

Tags: c#, sockets, exception, .net-core

This may sound stupid, but I just can't catch an `ExtendedSocketException` that is getting thrown by `SocketTaskExtensions.ConnectAsync()`.

The full namespace is: `System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory.ExtendedSocketException`

The compiler complains with `Cannot resolve symbol 'ExtendedSocketException'`. Both my class library and test projects are targeting .Net Core 2.1.

Also there is no such reference or Nuget package that could be added. At least I coudn't find anything... Also there seems nothing on https://learn.microsoft.com...

What am I doing wrong here?

```
[Fact]
[Trait("Category", "UnitTest")]
public async Task Should_Throw_Exception_If_Port_Unreachable()
{
    // Arrange
    var client = new TcpConnector();
    var nonListeningPort = 81;
    var endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), nonListeningPort);

    // Act & Assert
    var connectTask = client.ConnectAsync(endpoint);
    Func<Task> func = async () => { await connectTask; };

    func.Should().Throw<ExtendedSocketException>();
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. The exception is an internal .NET type. While you might run across it in the debugger, your own code should never see it. What makes you think you should?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ExtendedSocketException` is a `private` class so you can't reference it outside of .NET internals. You can catch `SocketException` however and inspect the exception message.

Comment: There's no such thing as a (non-nested) `private class`.

Comment: I know about them. But `System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory.ExtendedSocketException` is not a nested type. I stand by my claim. I do note that the OP's post may not be entirely correct, as they may have meant to refer to `System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException`, which would be a private class. But then your "answer" (and I use the term loosely) should clarify that if that's what you mean.

Comment: @PeterDuniho there is now :)

Answer (score 5):

Even though the `ExtendedSocketException` is meant to be private, it's definitely being exposed:
[image: ExtendedSocketException]

On the other hand, it inherits from `SocketException`, so we shouldn't need to care about it too much.

In terms of your test, I assume that you should be able to modify your assertion to something similar to:

```
var exception = Assert.Catch(func);
Assert.IsInstanceOf<SocketException>(exception);
Assert.That(exception.Message.Contains("actively refused"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`ExtendedSocketException` is derived from `SocketException` (for .NET Core). This can still be handled by using a catch block catching `SocketException`. We are able to confirm this through `System.Type.IsAssignableFrom(Type c)`:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
     Debug.Write(typeof(SocketException).IsAssignableFrom(e.GetType()));
}
```

In xUnit, the assertion can be:

```
var client = new TcpClient();
Task result() => client.ConnectAsync(IPAddress.Loopback, 23000);
var ex = Record.ExceptionAsync(async () => await client.ConnectAsync(IPAddress.Loopback, 23000));
Assert.IsAssignableFrom<SocketException>(ex.Result);
```